# Short Python function returning None, when explicit return statement present

Tags: python, return, nonetype

I was working on a CodeWars kata (Recursive reverse string), and I kept getting the wrong answer. I have the following file `test.py`

```
def reverse(s):
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s
    return s

print(reverse("dlrow olleh"))
```

And the entire execution from a new terminal, from the same directory as test.py is as follows:

```
brandonheinrich:~/workspace (nesting) $ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
None
>>> 
brandonheinrich:~/workspace (nesting) $
```

This same behavior happens when run directly.

```
brandonheinrich:~/workspace (nesting) $ python test.py
None
brandonheinrich:~/workspace (nesting) $
```

As requested:

```
>>> print repr(open("test.py").read())
'def reverse(s):\n    if len(s) == 1:\n        return s\n\treturn s\n\t\nprint(reverse("dlrow olleh"))'
```

Can someone explain why this return `None`?

It it's relevant, I'm having this error both on CodeWars interpreter, and on Python 2.7.6, running on Cloud9.

Comment: It prints `dlrow olleh` on my computer in Python 3.4.

Comment: Works fine with my Python 2.7.10. Can you share some more context please? Perhaps you're misdiagnozing?

Comment: The function posted always returns the string argument. Since recursion was mentioned, I suppose there should be something like 'return str[SOME SLICE]'?
Also, the function returns argument for me: Python 2.7.3 on Windows.

Comment: Your code is fine. There must be something more to the problem.

Comment: The function you posted should work.  Check to make sure that's in fact what you're using, including indentation, blank lines, etc. etc.  More context would be helpful.  You should try to provide an example that can be run and that reproduces the problem.

Comment: By the way, it's a really bad idea to use `str` as a variable name, since that's a built-in data type in Python.  Regardless of this problem, you should change the name to something like `s`.

Comment: Probably the real question is why you used *str* as a parameter name, aside from your question.

Comment: I've revised it to show the entire file I am running and the entire series of commands I'm using in the terminal.

Comment: And I used _str_ as the parameter name as that was the function template given to me by CodeWars

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `print repr(open("test.py").read())`?

Comment: Ah, that's it.  You're using mixed indentation, both spaces and tabs (run `python -tt test.py` to confirm).  Look at your second `return s` line -- there's tab indentation.  That means that your last `return s` isn't *really*  where it's supposed to be, it only looks like it is.  Switch to using four-space indentation throughout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed tabs and spaces. Both `return` statements are actually inside the `if`. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor to see it, and run Python with the `-tt` flag to make it complain about ambiguous indentation.

Comment: Do most IDEs/text editors convert the two automatically? Because I've been using python for almost 3 years now, and this is the first time I've ever had this issue when the indentation lines up in the editor.

Comment: @BrandonHeinrich: Most programming text editors I've seen default to 4-space tab stops, but Python 2 uses the equivalent of 8-space tab stops. (Python 3 runs with `-tt` on all the time.)